# SocketScan always returns 100% battery life

Tags: ios, socketscan

I'm getting 100% as the result every time...why (iOS/ SocketScan API v.10.2.227)?
Here's my code:

```
-(void) onGetBatteryInfo:(ISktScanObject*)scanObj {

    SKTRESULT result=[[scanObj Msg]Result];
    if(SKTSUCCESS(result)){

        long batteryLevel = SKTBATTERY_GETCURLEVEL([[scanObj Property] getUlong]);
        NSLog(@"BatteryInfo %ld", batteryLevel);

        [self setBatteryLevel:batteryLevel];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"ES-GetBatteryInfo set status returned the error %ld",result);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Mark

[image: scanner config]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the framework you're using, but I would check [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryMonitoringEnabled. If monitoring is not enabled, you won't be able to get an accurate read.

Comment: Mark, are you sure that the battery level isn't 100%? What does it say in the [Scanner Settings app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scannersettings/id456055932?mt=8). If it's not 100%, are using the battery level notifications or querying the battery level using getProperty?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  It says 72%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you double check the following...

In `viewDidLoad` you create ScanApiHelper and a timer

```
if(ScanApi==nil) {
    ScanApi=[[ScanApiHelper alloc]init];
    [ScanApi setDelegate:self];
    [ScanApi open];
    ScanApiConsumer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.2 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Your timer calls `doScanApiReceive`

```
-(void)onTimer: (NSTimer*)theTimer{
    if(theTimer==ScanApiConsumer){
        [ScanApi doScanApiReceive];
    }
}
```

Finally, you don't query the battery level until after you've received an `onDeviceArrival` notification

```
-(void)onDeviceArrival:(SKTRESULT)result device:(DeviceInfo*)deviceInfo {
    [ScanApi postGetBattery:deviceInfo Target:self Response:@selector(onGetBatteryInfo:)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  I was calling it too soon.